# Neural network activation function

Tags: java, neural-network

I've finally had time building my own ANN library, however I'm having some difficulties understanding some behaviors.

Here are some activation functions I coded:

```
DoubleFunction<Double> sigmoid = x -> 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
DoubleFunction<Double> sigmoidDer = x -> {
    double s = sigmoid.apply(x);
    return s * (1 - s);
};

DoubleFunction<Double> tanh = Math::tanh;
DoubleFunction<Double> tanhDer = x -> 1. - Math.pow(tanh.apply(x), 2);

DoubleFunction<Double> relu = x -> Math.max(0, x);
DoubleFunction<Double> reluDer = x -> {
    if (x < 0)
        return 0;
    return 1;
};

DoubleFunction<Double> softPlus = x -> Math.log(1 + Math.exp(x));
```

In my code I'm simply selecting a pair to serve as the activation function (+ derivative).

None of my functions convege to a solution (I'm trying to get the net to learn XOR operator) but the tanh function and its derivative.

Note: I am using a bias neuron for each layer that outputs constant 1.

I've checked [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function) out but apparently I'm missing something fundamental here.

Does anyone care to enlighten me?

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12197/can-a-2-2-1-feedforward-neural-network-with-sigmoid-activation-functions-represe

Comment: That is very interesting. Care to explain why It cannot be done with logistic function (why does the mapping matter)?
Also, I am using a bias neuron for each layer with their output set as 1. Does it matter in that case?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with this subject, but it seems that the function's range is 0..1, excluding it's bounds (so `(0, 1)`). So it can never reach a perfect 0 or 1.

Comment: That is correct, which is why I said "converges". the outputs will never reach 0 nor 1 however they should come really close to it. As of now when I use `tanh` I get the correct outputs (example: for the inputs (0,0) I get the output 0.0003 which is not 0 but really close to it - that is a good behavior) however when I use the classic logistic function I get 0.48-0.51 output so even if I round it to the closest integer sometimes for the input (0,0) I get 0 but some other times I get 1. My point is when I'm using logistic function the output is inconsistent.